# how to use wsadata structure MASM32

Tags: assembly, winsock2, masm32

I'm trying to build a very simple client at masm32 (my first time at, I had little previous experience with tasm).
I'm trying to initialize the Winsock dll with WSAStartup, and I have to give it wsadata stracutre.

I tried to do it like this but I get an error:

```
.data
    wsadata WSADATA <>

.code

main:
    invoke WSAStartup, 101H, offset wsadata
    invoke ExitProcess, 0
end main
```

errors

```
client.asm(15) : error A2008: syntax error : wsadata 
client.asm(24) : error A2006: undefined symbol : wsadata 
client.asm(24) : error A2114: INVOKE argument type mismatch : argument : 2
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: What if you use `addr` instead of `offset` ?

Comment: @Michael Same error

Comment: btw, can you try different name? I think MASM is generally not case sensitive, so using `wsadata` vs `WSAData` may cause some trouble sooner or later, overshadowing the struct definition with symbol, or failing to do so.

Comment: @Ped7g, Although I added "option casemap: none" which makes the code case sensitive, I tried to change the name and still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

you  probably have an unprintable character in front of wsadata

if your editor has show all character option use it or

delete the line and retype it from column 0

both addr as well as offset wsadata should assemble properly without error

```
E:\wsadatatest>type wsadatatest.asm
.386
.model flat , stdcall

option casemap:none

include e:\masm32\include\windows.inc
include e:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include e:\masm32\include\user32.inc
include e:\masm32\include\ws2_32.inc

includelib e:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib e:\masm32\lib\user32.lib
includelib e:\masm32\lib\ws2_32.lib

.data
caption db "masm wsadata test",0
message db "masm wsadata test",0
wsaData   WSADATA <>

.code
start:
    invoke MessageBoxA,NULL,offset caption,offset message,MB_OK
    invoke WSAStartup,0101h,ADDR wsaData
    invoke WSAStartup,0101h,offset wsaData
    invoke ExitProcess,0
end start
E:\wsadatatest>makeit.bat
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.14.8444
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1981-1997.  All rights reserved.

 Assembling: wsadatatest.asm

***********
ASCII build
***********

 Volume in drive E is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is CEC6-E6A8

 Directory of E:\wsadatatest

12/07/2017  12:33 AM               627 wsadatatest.asm
12/07/2017  12:39 AM             2,048 wsadatatest.exe
12/07/2017  12:39 AM             1,173 wsadatatest.obj
               3 File(s)          3,848 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  94,127,931,392 bytes free
Press any key to continue . . .
```